# Shouldn't the old access token be invalidated by a refresh call?

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, token, access-token, fosoauthserverbundle

When I refresh an OAuth access token `A`, I get an new access token `B`. But `A` is still valid, I can still use it.

Shouldn't the old access token be invalidated by the refresh operation? If not, if it's "by design", could someone give me details about why?

Note: using Symfony with the FOSOAuthServerBundle bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RFC6749 section 1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) indicates that:

> Refresh tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are
> used to obtain [...] additional access tokens
> with identical or narrower scope

As far as I understand, the access token `A` may be still valid when an access token `B` is issued with the refreh token.